# How to change a sub-domain name and redirect using the old name

Tags: dns, subdomain, windows-server

Alright, here's the dilemma I have.  First off, I am by far not a Windows Server person.  Not a huge fan of it at all, but I have no choice but to use it where I am.

I have a domain example.ag.mydomain.com

I would like to change this to example1.ag.mydomain.com

However, I want to be able to set it so if someone goes to example.ag.mydomain.com/wordpress it will redirect them to example1.ag.mydomain.com/wordpress.

I do have access to the DNS but I really have no clue how to do this, would this be a wildcard DNS or would this need to be set up differently?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You can't do HTTP redirect in DNS, you need to do it from webserver (exact configuration steps depend on webserver software, but it should be fairly easy in any case)

Comment: Will this work for anything, because the requested folder/file won't always be know...so I want it to be dynamic for any file or folder request made.

Comment: That is very common requirement. Again: exact configuration steps depend on webserver software, but it should be fairly easy in any case